# java.sql.time comparison in rule execution drools

Tags: java, time, drools, rule-engine

when i tried to execute the below mentioned rule, got run-time exceptions from drools engine,

Rule:

```
package com.org.model; 

rule "Rule "
when
    messageObj: com.org.model.message(myTime after 00:00:00, myTime before 23:00:00 )  

then
    messageObj.setMessage("Completed");
end
```

tried using `myTime >=00:00:00, myTime <= 23:00:00` 
`myTime after 00:00:00, myTime before 23:00:00` also
myTime - java.sql.Time  - 00:00:00 format

Error :

```
Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=com/rule/myDrl.drl, line=5, column=0
   text=[ERR 102] Line xx:xx mismatched input ':' in rule "Rule "], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=com/rule/myDrl.drl, line=0, column=0
   text=Parser returned a null Package]]
```

Comment: My guess is that you should import the Message class and rewrite your when clause like `messageObj: Message(myTime after 00:00:00, myTime before 23:00:00 ) `.

Comment: @LaercioMetzner  i tried using that import also,but error didn't change

Comment: I thought the mistake could be the class name, check if the message class is declared with an uppercase letter like `Message`, if so i would suggest you to rewrite your when clause like I mentioned in my previous comment. Also I'm not sure about the usage of the temporal operators in your when clause, I would suggest you to check the manual if the error persists. https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch09.html#d0e13104